# Pause foreach loop unitl event occurs, after which loop continues (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

A forEach loop walks through an array and performs a certain action. However, when it arrives at 'b' it is expected to pause after which it can be continued until a button is pressed.

The button should not reactivate the loop directly, rather it is an event which has to occur before continuing. Specifically, when pressing the button the 'b', its value become a 'c' which would let the loop continue. It is thus important that later elements are not processed by the loop before the button is pressed.

How would you put this in the forEach loop?

```
array.forEach(item => {
  if (item == 'a') {
    console.log(item)
  }

  if (item == 'b') {
    pause until button is pressed, and only then continue with the next step
  }


  })
```

Comment: Consider using a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way around this, instead of relying on recursion, is to simply use `await` inside a native `for` loop (`Array.prototype.forEach` does not allow asynchronous operation within it). In this way, when your item is `b`, you simply await for a certain event (e.g. a button press), which will resolve the promise and allow the loop to continue. Pseudo-code wise, it will look something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  if (item === 'b') {
    await waitForButtonClick();
  }

  console.log(item);
}
```

Of course, for the above the work, you will need to wrap it inside an `async` function... until [JS catches up to allow top level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) ;)

The `waitForButtonClick()` is expected to return a promise. Inside the button click, you can, for example, wait for a click event to trigger before resolving the promise:

```
function waitForButtonClick() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', resolve);
  });
}
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

async function processArray() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i];
    
    if (item === 'b') {
      console.log('Encoutered b, waiting for button click');
      await waitForButtonClick();
      console.log('Ok, now we can continue');
    }

    console.log(item);
  }
}

function waitForButtonClick() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', resolve);
  });
}

// Process array
processArray();
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Click to confirm <code>b</code></button>
```

Comment: you can use `for...of` to keep that `forEach` feel:  https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-haze-6h8uw

Comment: hah, that codesandbox was acting screwy. It threw me for a loop for longer than I care to admit. I accidentally put the logger div beneath the script tag. Woops.